# Copy and Paste Rtf format

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to copy a portion of a rtf file from one RichTextBox to another.

My code:

```
Dim wk As New Work
```

Work is a form with a RichTextEdit on it

```
Clipboard.SetText(wk.rtb1.SelectedText, TextDataFormat.Rtf)
```

I copy a section of a rtf file on WorkForm into clipboard. This seeems to work

Then I try to set this into another RichTextBox

```
If (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)) Then
        rtb1.Rtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
End If
```

But when I do the GetText I get an error
"File Format is not valid"

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I think you want `wk.rtb1.SelectedRtf` not `wk.rtb1.SelectedText`

Comment: Spot on this fixed, all is good . Thanks